# How to enable "View State" option for ExecuteScript processor in NiFi UI?

Tags: python, state, apache-nifi

I am using NiFi **ExecuteScript** with python. In the python script I add/modify state of the processor

```
stateManager = context.getStateManager()
stateManager.setState(newmap, Scope.LOCAL)
```

Is there anyway I can view/clear the processor state in NiFi web ui?

Some other processors like **TailFile** give you this option via *"view state"* when you right click on the processor but ExecuteScript right click does not give you this option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most processors that store state have an annotation on them @Stateful which indicates to the framework that they store state, and is used to enabled features such as the "View State".

Since ExecuteScript doesn't store state itself it doesn't currently have this annotation, but since scripts can access the state manager and store state we should add the annotation so that View State works. I created this JIRA:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-2885